# How can I make the Gnome3 calendar use Thunderbird instead of Evolution?

Tags: opensuse, gnome3, gnome-shell, thunderbird

Can it be done? I don't want to use Evolution's calendar... I want to keep using Thunderbird... I have to add some addons (like *lightning*) first right?

My goal is to have some calendar-like on thunderbird and replace the one of Evolution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, I found how to do this at [How to change gnome-shell calendar default application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69349/how-to-change-gnome-shell-calendar-default-application)

Just execute this in a terminal!!

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.office.calendar exec thunderbird
```

I have tested it and it works!! (it's not exaclty what I wanted but it's a start)

Answer (score 3):

Go to **System->Preferences->Preferred Applications**.

On the first tab, change the **Mail Reader** settings.

**UPDATE**

If you don't have your email client in the drop down menu. You got to specify it manually in the Command field. For example, `/usr/bin/thunderbird "%s"`

**UPDATE**

It does not seem to actually solve the problem, although it should. Perhaps it's a bug. The [second answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41677/12698) is actually working.

Comment: ok... founded what you mention but the thunderbird option does not appear...

Comment: see the update in my post

Comment: Thanks @Ganga that can add thunderbird to the **Mail Reader** settings, but looks like it more a calendar settings: I installed the lighning add-on I want to check if I can add that... **where can I find some info?**

Comment: oh i see. you should add to your question some more details about your final goal by describing the plugin you install and what features you actually want to make work.

Comment: also try the second solution suggested in the next post, just in case.

Comment: just added more details thanks again @Ganga

Comment: the second answer should actually work. try it!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is the following:

```
cd /usr/bin
ln -s ./thunderbird evolution
```

That creates a symbolic link that mapps the application call "evolution" to "thunderbird".

Because the Gnome Calendar Extensions starts `evolution -c calendar`, the link will start thunderbird (which ignores the `-c` parameter). That should work everywhere.

Comment: this seems sketchy at best. not only have you left a bunch of files around in e.g. `/usr/lib`, wasting space, but this will probably get overwritten with a package upgrade. plus, it requires root.

Answer (score 0):

Thunderbird can be set as default calendar application by opening the file:
`$HOME/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`* in a text-editor such as GEdit and adding the line:

```
text/calendar=thunderbird.desktop
```

to the [Default Applications] section.

You may or may not need to add that same line to the [Added Associations] section too.

*To find and open this file, press the button combo <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> in your `/home` folder, and look for `.local`, then find the file, right-click it and select "Open with...", or just double-click. After adding the line, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>, answer YES when asked to save"

Works in OpenSuse/Gnome 3.8-3.10

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Tested in Ubuntu 14.04 with Gnome Shell 3.10. Not even after restarting Gnome Shell.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line to the .local/share/applications/mimeapps.list worked in Arch with Gnome3.

```
[Default Applications]
text/calendar=userapp-Thunderbird-NXJNAX.desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to view Thunderbird events on the GNOME notification/calendar display through this extension: EDS Calendar Integration -  https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/search/?q=EDS%20Calendar%20Integration&appver=115.3.1&platform=Linux